# PHP Asset Packaging Library

Tags: php

anyone know a great asset management/packaging library for PHP making asset (images, css, js) deployment and optimization super easy much like [Jammit for Rails](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any integrated ones, but you can probably start off by combining [JSMin](http://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php/) and [CSSMin](http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/) into one for javascript and CSS files accordingly.

Regarding images, I'm not sure how you want to optimize them. Something like [75% JPEG compression?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Apache ant to build my minified versions of CSS and JS, it's also quite handy on doing other related build tasks.

My build.xml looks like this:

```
 <concat destfile="global.concat.css" fixlastline="yes">
  <fileset file="skeleton/stylesheets/base.css" />
  <fileset file="skeleton/stylesheets/skeleton.css" />
  <fileset file="skeleton/stylesheets/layout.css" />
  <fileset file="global.css" />
</concat>

<exec executable="java">
  <arg value="-jar" />
  <arg value="/usr/bin/yuicompressor.jar"/>
  <arg path="global.concat.css" />
  <arg value="-o" />
  <arg value="global.min.css" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

About a Year ago i wrote a little library called [Packtacular](https://github.com/mario-deluna/packtacular).

To be honest if I look at it now there is alot of stuff i would do diffrent today.

The good thing about it is that its really simple to use. You can basically just tell Packtacular a path that contains files and it will merge them together and take care if one of them changes (Wich does make deployment pretty easy too).

```
Packtacular::css( 'assets/css/', 'cache/stylesheet_:time.css' );
```

In that example it will take all `.css` files inside `assets/css/` and merge them into one file under `cache/stylesheet_:time.css`. `:time` represents the timestamp of the "newest" file. Means you want have trouble with browser cache.

Compression or optimisation of the assets you have to implement by your own using filters:

```
Packtacular::filter( 'css', function( $data ) 
{
    // do some cool stuff with $data
    return $data;
});
```

**If your looking for something simple based on PHP it might work for you. But if need something more I would suggest using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic).**